# How to use background-position: center; behaviour on svg pattern?

Tags: svg

I'm using an svg with a pattern in it. The svg is the full width of the browser window. When I resize the browser, I want the svg pattern to expand from the center of the svg(`background-position: center;` behaviour).

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  }
  
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="pat" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <polygon points="12,5 7,5 7,0 5,0 5,5 0,5 0,7 5,7 5,12 7,12 7,7 12,7 "/>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#pat)" />
</svg>
```

When you run the snippet en resize the result window. The pattern is expanded and contract from the left top. I want the pattern to expand and contract from the center of the svg. Is this possible

Comment: You can move the pattern by changing x and/or y. Ultimately you'd be better off with objectBoundingBox co-ordinates though.

Comment: @RobertLongson yes I know, but changing x or y doesn't make the svg expand and contract from the center like `background-postition: center`, does it? And What are the pro's of using `objectBoundingBox`?

Comment: In objectBoundingBox units 0.5, 0.5 is the centre of the shape so it's much easier to centre things.

Comment: Ahh, that would be usefull indeed, will fix that. But it doesn't solve my main problem.

Comment: Sure it does, draw the pattern contents round the origin and then set the pattern position to 0.5, 0.5

Comment: The problem with that approach is that it is not easy to keep the pattern size at 24x24, which I assume OP wants (?).

Comment: That was indeed what I wanted. @RobertLongson, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the origin of the coordinates (and therefore the pattern) is at the top left of the SVG.  To centre the pattern, you have to get that origin to the centre of the SVG.

Normal `transform` attributes can't do that because they don't take percentages.  The only way to achieve it is to use a `<use>` element.  It's `x` and `y` attributes are effectively a `trannsform` but they do allow percentages.

So the solution is to make the `<rect>` 100% width and height, but position it at `x="-50%" y="-50%"` so that its centre is at the origin.  We then move the origin to (50%, 50%) with our `<use>` element.

*Click "Full page" for the best view*

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  }
  
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="pat" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <polygon points="12,5 7,5 7,0 5,0 5,5 0,5 0,7 5,7 5,12 7,12 7,7 12,7 "/>
    </pattern>
    <rect id="rect" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#pat)" />
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#rect" x="50%" y="50%"/>
</svg>
```

But if you try this, it will still not appear to be centred.  That's because your cross symbol is not centred in your 24x24 pattern. If we reposition the cross so that it is in the centre of the pattern, you get this:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  }
  
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="pat" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <polygon points="18,11 13,11 13,6 11,6 11,11 6,11 6,13 11,13 11,18 13,18 13,13 18,13 "/>
    </pattern>
    <rect id="rect" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#pat)" />
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#rect" x="50%" y="50%"/>
</svg>
```